# Which Sample Library was that? (Alternative sounds from conventional instruments)

Tags: samples

Hi,

I remember coming across a small boutique recording company that releases sample libraries of otherworldly sounds produced by placing contact mics on standard instruments or using alternative techniques reminiscent of "prepared-piano" etc...

Does anyone know the name of that company I'm thinking of?

Comment: maybe Tim's library....
http://hissandaroar.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly VERY similar to the aforementioned hissandroar tortured piano, but it's not that. There are maybe only 2 or 3 libraries available from this company and they are all similar in vein to the tortured piano

Comment: not to push my own agenda here then but it's possible you are referring to echocollectivefx.com

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like the libraries I made for Vir2 instruments "Fractured" and "Violence"
http://www.vir2.com/instruments/fractured-prepared-acoustic-guitar
http://www.vir2.com/instruments/violence

Answer (score 0):

Sonic Couture?

http://www.soniccouture.com/en/

or was it Tonehammer?

they split into two companies:

8Dio
http://8dio.com/

Soundiron
http://www.soundiron.com/

Comment: @tim thanks for turning me into the Soundiron one!  Makes me now want to finally invest in Knotakt in order to make use of some of those libraries on there (amongst others) for design.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using same techniques too: [www.audiority.com](http://www.audiority.com)